# Помогите с регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка:

```
$test = '<w:t>${</w:t></w:r>nzk</w:t></w:r><w:prooferr w:type="spellEnd">}</w:t>';
```

Нужно заменить эту строку на любое слово, пробую так:

```
$tr  = preg_replace("/\$\{.*nzk.*\}/", $replace, $test);
```

Ничего не получается, что у меня не так?

Comment: Sh4dow, так как места в том сообщении уже нет, пишу сюда:
Спасибо, что всё разъяснил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tr = preg_replace('/\${.*nzk.*}/', $replace, $test);
```

Comment: не помогает этот способ(

Comment: [Чего?](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test27.php)

Comment: Блин, не понимаю тогда почему у меня не работает, полностью копирю отсюда(

Comment: Мобыть вы $test выводите?) Или кавычки двойные оставили?

Comment: ДА, это кавычки) Спасибо) А почему двойные нельзя?

Comment: А вообще вопросики и не нужны, ошибка была именно в кавычках))

Comment: Потому что в них ищутся переменные и вообще они себя иногда странно ведут. Вполне, что php в вашем варианте искал переменную с именем "`.*nzk.*\`"

    $a = array('b' => 'lol');
    echo "{$a['b']}"; // lol

Comment: Да, вопросики уже убрал, это че-то я повелся) Вопрос - это {0,1}, звездочка - {0,}, так что правильно, не нужны)

Answer (score 1):

```
.*   ->   .*?
$ perl 
my $test = '<w:t>${</w:t></w:r>nzk</w:t></w:r><w:prooferr w:type="spellEnd">}</w:t>';
print $test, "\n";
$test =~ s|\$\{.*?nzk.*?\}|bla-bla-bla|;
print $test, "\n";
<w:t>${</w:t></w:r>nzk</w:t></w:r><w:prooferr w:type="spellEnd">}</w:t>
<w:t>bla-bla-bla</w:t>
```

Comment: не помогло(

Comment: значит вы не то написали.
добавил в ответ пример на perl.